# Is TypeScript a superset of ES6?

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6

In other words, is all ES6 syntax covered by TypeScript?

How is my question differente from:

- "Is TypeScript really a superset of JavaScript?"

  **ES6** isn't (or hasn't been considered if you read this in the futur) the current version of Javascript
- Is Typescript != ES6?

  **It's different**, I know that, not what I'm asking.

Comment: I don't get why this question is being downvoted and closed?

Comment: It's an objective question and should not have been closed.  Apparently the answer is "not at this time." Perhaps the roadmap for TypeScript is to be able to handle all ES6 constructs in a future version?

Comment: See [What does "all legal JavaScript is legal TypeScript" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41750390/what-does-all-legal-javascript-is-legal-typescript-mean)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Based on the [current language specification](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#1) available at the website:

> TypeScript is a syntactic sugar for JavaScript. TypeScript syntax is a superset of Ecmascript 5 (ES5) syntax.

And:

> TypeScript syntax includes several proposed features of Ecmascript 6 (ES6), including classes and modules.

Comment: The spec link is broken and probably should be updated to https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#1. Also, you probably want to update the quoted text as ES2015 is what's mentioned now.

Comment: Agreed that's what's written on GitHub, but it's not entirely true. See for example http://blog.jonasbandi.net/2016/10/myth-of-superset.html - there are many example of perfectly valid ECMA6 that will NOT be valid in typescript, AND vice-versa. IMHO there is a dangerous divergence here.

Answer (score 6):

[TypeScript 1.5 (February 2015)](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v1.5.4/doc/spec.md#1-introduction) was the last version not to claim to be a superset of ES6:

> TypeScript syntax is a superset of Ecmascript 5 (ES5) syntax.

As of [TypeScript 1.6 (August 2015)](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v1.6.2/doc/spec.md#1-introduction):

> TypeScript syntax is a superset of ECMAScript 6 (ES6) syntax.

The wording was changed in [TypeScript 1.8 (January 2016)](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v1.8.2/doc/spec.md#1), but the meaning is the same:

> TypeScript syntax is a superset of ECMAScript 2015 (ES2015) syntax.

So, yes: **According to the spec, TypeScript is a superset of ES6.**

Comment: Your bolded conclusion omits the word "syntax", which is absolutely crucial.

Answer (score 1):

While all syntactically valid ES6 programs are syntactically valid Typescript programs, it is not necessarily the case that those programs mean the same thing or have the same runtime behaviour in both languages. Consider the code below:

```js
const A = 1, B = 2;
function foo(x) { return x; }

console.log(foo<A, B>(3));
```

In Typescript, [this program compiles](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strict=false&noImplicitAny=false&strictNullChecks=false&strictFunctionTypes=false&strictPropertyInitialization=false&strictBindCallApply=false&noImplicitThis=false&noImplicitReturns=false&alwaysStrict=false&esModuleInterop=false&declaration=false&target=2#code/FAYw9gdgzgLgBAQTgXjgRgDRwEIrgJgG5gAzAVwhBgEtI4SwwAKADwEo4BvOAJwFMYZHhDgtCcAL7BQkKGAA2fAHTywAcyYMwAHgRZsAPiYBmNm2JA) (with 3 errors) and logs the number 3 to the console. However, in ES6 this program logs the value `false` twice, since `foo<A` is false and `B>(3)` is false.

So, while Typescript is a *syntactic* superset of ES6, it is not exactly accurate to say that the language is a superset. That said, the vast majority of real-world ES6 code will not have this kind of issue.

Answer (score 0):

Typescript is similar to JS with some extended features like type checking, and OOp support.
https://lackydev.com/typescript-for-beginners-and-overview-of-typescript/