# Is Typescript a superset of Node.js?

Tags: node.js, typescript

I'm writing an application in Typescript, and I have found some sample Node.js code on the internet. Can I use Node.js code as Typescript?

IE: Is Typescript a superset of Node.js?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32369863/is-typescript-a-superset-of-es6) was suggested as a duplicate. But it isn't because it only addresses the relationship between Typescript and Javascript, and doesn't say anything about Node.js.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is TypeScript a superset of ES6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32369863/is-typescript-a-superset-of-es6)

Comment: Is a programming language a superset of a runtime?

Comment: Node.js is not a programming language, so you cannot write "in Node.js". The language used for node.js is JavaScript and TypeScript is an additional layer on top of javascript .

Comment: Node.js is not a language. Node is a Javascript runtime.

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript is a superset of JavaScript which means that you can write JavaScript code inside TypeScript but not vice-versa. TypeScript is compiled to JavaScript. Node.js is a JavaScript runtime. To use TypeScript with Node.js you need to install it using `npm install typescript --save-dev`